# Cannot pass Global Variables to Multiple Functions inside a Module in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, maya

After going through every possible resources I came to conclusion  that I need an urgent help to pass global variables from a function to others inside a Module in Python.

Actually I am writing a small UI in Autodesk Maya2010, here is a brief about the problem.

In the following code  I have got two Module Level Global Variables, I am assigning values to them inside a function. Now if I pass these variables directly(i.e. without converting the function call and assigning it as a string) then the code works fine, however since the **Command Flag** of the **Button Function** only allows a string or a function name hence I am stuck with this way of calling the function.

The result which I get is :

temp_var=None

a_Window=None

which I have got no idea about.

Can anyone point down what exactly is happening when I use the string value as function call?

```
**The sample code**:


import maya.cmds;
temp_var=None;
a_Window=None;
def im_PrimaryFunc():
    imSecondary_func();

def imSecondary_func():
    global a_Window;
    global temp_var;
    a_Window=maya.cmds.window(title="Something");
    a_layout=maya.cmds.columnLayout(adj=1,rs=10);
    temp_var=maya.cmds.createNode("polySphere");
    func_call="a_calledFunc(a_Window,temp_var)";
    maya.cmds.button(label="call_aFunc",align="center",command=func_call);
    maya.cmds.showWindow(a_Window);

def a_calledFunc(arg00,arg01):
    print(arg00);
    print(arg01);
```

Comment: Don't use semicolons.

Comment: not using semi-colons would solve the issue?

Comment: @user1507332: No, that's why it was written as a *comment*, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import maya.cmds
from functools import partial
temp_var=None
a_Window=None
def im_PrimaryFunc():
    imSecondary_func()

def imSecondary_func():
    global a_Window
    global temp_var
    a_Window=maya.cmds.window(title="Something")
    a_layout=maya.cmds.columnLayout(adj=1,rs=10)
    temp_var=maya.cmds.createNode("polySphere")
    maya.cmds.button(label="call_aFunc",align="center",command = partial(a_calledFunc,temp_var, a_Window))
    maya.cmds.showWindow(a_Window)

def a_calledFunc(arg00,arg01, part):
    print(arg00)
    print(arg01)

im_PrimaryFunc()
```

Remember that you are writing python code so there is no need to add ; in your code :)

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what you changed and why it would work as you wrote it.  Maybe you can clarify what it is that you changed?

Comment: Oh yeah, first his code was working for me and I am not sure why its not working for him. I made some cleanup I think he is coming from mel so removed the;. And the other main thing in `func_call="a_calledFunc(a_Window,temp_var)";` changed to `partial(a_calledFunc,temp_var, a_Window)` for more safty.

Comment: hey Achayan! Thanks for the reply unfortunately I am away from my stuff. I will try this for sure once I am back. I am not aware of "partial" module though  :) Will try it for sure

Comment: yup It worked Achayan Awesome :), I'll go through functools module. Moreover, while using the "partial" now I do no need to declare variables global. Earlier the program was having issues with the way Maya imports variables in to the global namespace,especially when I was importing this script as a module. Thanks Again.

Comment: okie dokie did that already and thanks once again that was quite helpful!